# How can I induce context switches for the purpose of concurrency testing on .NET Core?

Tags: .net, multithreading, testing, context-switch

I'm trying to perform concurrency testing of a concurrent data structure. My strategy is to run the test on many threads and hope for as many context switches as possible. Every context switch is an opportunity for a race condition to manifest.

.NET Core has no (supported) way of suspending threads.

How can I induce as many context switches at random locations as possible?

I have already tried changing the thread priority. I changed the test thread's priority to idle and started other threads at a higher priority doing busy work (`while (true);`) to keep all CPU cores occupied. Unfortunately, on Windows 10, this does not reliably deschedule the low priority thread. I would have expected that it is descheduled and then not rescheduled. Both assumptions appear to be false.

What else could I try to cause as many context switches as possible at random points in the program?

Comment: [`Thread.Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.yield?view=netcore-2.0) seems to be available from .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: @Charlieface That would trigger switching at a known point, not inside data structure code.

Answer (score 0):

Through testing I found that it is possible to do this by setting thread affinity. Changing affinity moves the thread to another core immediately. I was able to create basically arbitrary amounts of context switches that way.

In order to time the context switches randomly and in rapid succession, we need a timer with less than 1ms precision. This appears to be impossible on Windows. But a polling loop using `Stopwatch` can achieve nanosecond precision. The cost of this is that one CPU core must be burned for the timer loop.

In this way, any scheduling of threads can be orchestrated precisely.